# MySQL slow query log empty commit

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

I am using AWS RDS slow log querys on a mysql database.
I have a lot of this in the log:

```
# Query_time: 0.613015  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use XXXXXXX;
SET timestamp=1567605603;
commit;
```

Some like this:

```
# Query_time: 0.575397  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1567605603;
commit;
```

What this means? A transaction was open but without any DML operations?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832912/how-can-set-timestamp-be-a-slow-query might be of help here.

Comment: Please post 100 lines before and 100 lines after your point of concern from your Slow Query Log and we will have a better idea what was going on with your instance and can point you to a reference that would tie to PID displayed on SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; results, when available.  10 Seconds of a GENERAL LOG would be very enlightening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't know from a single entry in the slow query log, but it's likely that this `commit` was the last statement run after some number of DML statements.

That is, each statement gets its own entry in the slow query log, including `start transaction` and `commit`.

Unfortunately, the entries in the slow query log don't have a transaction id, so we don't know which statements are part of the same transaction.